# DAX expression is not a valid table expression

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Create a measure inside the Calculations table which calculates which takes the sum of line price and filters on the product category "Bikes" and YEAR(Sales[OrderDate]) year being 2018.

Name this measure 2018 Bikes Revenue.
the code solution is

```
2018 Bikes Revenue =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Sales[LinePrice] ),
    Sales[ProductCategory] = "Bikes",
    YEAR ( Sales[OrderDate] ) = 2018
)
```

it shows errors "The expression specified in the query is not a valid table expression."
need help here

Answer (score 2):

Your error message indicates that you are trying to use your DAX formula to create a **calculated table**. However, the result of your expression is a single number so you can only use it as a **calculated measure**. Take care to use the proper UI for your formula

[image]